# SQL statement returns a resultset on an empty table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, derby

```
        String sql = "Select MAX(ORDERLINEID) From ORDERLINESTABLE";
        ResultSet rst;
        rst = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        if(rst.next())
        {
            next = rst.getInt("ORDERLINEID");
            next++;
        }
```

I have a table called ORDERLINESTABLE in my database which is currently empty. I have run the above code with the aim is to get the highest integer stored in the ORDERLINEID column allowing me to increment it when adding items to the database.

I expected this query to return nothing as the table is empty but when debugging I noticed that the search is returning true for the rst.next() method.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be? I have looked at the resultset.next() documentation and as far as I can see it should return false.

Comment: As to the "why", this is a fundamental SQL behavior, and it has to do with the basic academic theory of relational algebra and relational calculus and aggregate functions, etc. Here's a bit of a reference: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~wlam/compsci/sqlnulls

Comment: Thanks for that man, just favourited that link. Not going to pretend I understand all of it but enough that I can use it in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, look at your data.  Here is a sample query from any db engine.

```
select max(field) maxValue
from table
where 1=3
```

It will yield

```
maxValue
Null
```

In other words, your query is returning one record with a value of null.

Comment: Thanks, I ran the query and you were 100% right it is returning a null. Still not sure why but I can work with that. Really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to fetch the ORDERLINEID filled in by the database after the INSERT statement. Make the column ORDERLINEID of type INT AUTOINCREMENT.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ORDERLINESTABLE(xxx, yyy) VALUES (?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
    stmt.setString(1, xxx);
    stmt.setInt(2, yyy);
    int updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate(); // 1
    try (ResultSet id = stmt.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        if (id.next()) { // 'if' as just 1 row inserted.
            int orderLineId = id.getInt(1); // 1 key per row.
        }
    }
}
```

Java has a database independent way to fetch the generated keys of an INSERT. That is a lot safer than taking the MAX afterwards or before, in a multi-user environment.

Scenarios for wrong IDs are numerous in a multiuser environment:

- first SELECT
- second SELECT
- second increment for new ID
- first increment for new ID
- first INSERT
- second INSERT

Comment: I appreciate the info - The program I am making is a simple one for an assessment at my college and will only ever have one user logged in at a time but I will definitely use this info in the future so thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; appreciated